# Weird delayed-output behaviour when a process is invoked twice

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to write a counter having an input (start) and three outputs (tsy,tsr,tlg) that are asserted for 1 `clk_period` after 4, 6 and 16 `clk_period` respectively. The following code works fine for a single start assertion.

```
library ieee ;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all ;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all ;

entity proj_test is
  port (
    clk, start : in bit;
    tsy, tsr, tlg : out bit
  ) ;
end entity ; -- proj_test

architecture behav of proj_test is

constant clk_period : time := 100 ns;

begin

process (start)
begin
    if (start='1') then
        tsy <= '1' after 4*clk_period, '0' after 5*clk_period;
        tsr <= '1' after 6*clk_period, '0' after 7*clk_period;
        tlg <= '1' after 16*clk_period, '0' after 17*clk_period;
    end if;
end process;

end architecture ; -- behav
```

[Output for a single start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0YD1.png)

The `start` pulses are 400 ns apart, as driven by the below code:

```
library ieee ;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all ;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all ;

entity proj_test_test is
end entity proj_test_test; 

architecture behav of proj_test_test is
  constant clk_period : time := 100 ns;
  signal clk, start :  bit;
  signal tsy, tsr, tlg : bit;
begin

  P : entity work.proj_test port map (clk, start, tsy, tsr, tlg);

  start <= '0', 
           '1' after  2*clk_period,
           '0' after  3*clk_period,
           '1' after 6*clk_period,
           '0' after 7*clk_period,
           '1' after 42*clk_period;

end architecture behav;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/52mP

or the following simulator commands:

```
force -freeze sim:/proj_test/clk 0 0, 1 {50 ns} -r 100
force -freeze sim:/proj_test/start 1 0, 0 100, 1 400, 0 500
```

However, when I assert the input `start` for a second time, `tsy` spans for multiple clock periods.

[Output for an added start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCYuJ.png)

I'm trying to understand why. My guess is that the second process call "flushes" the assignments of the first one. Also, is there a better way to write the behaviour of this counter?

Comment: Are you trying to write code that can be synthesized?

Comment: @scary_jeff No, it's for a testbench.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The weird behaviour looks to be outside this code.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Edited the post with the complete code.

Comment: That still isn't an MCVE. There's nothing driving start. I added some code myself on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4ygx), which works fine.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I didn't use a testbench. Anyway, I edited your code to match my scenario. Please check [this](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/52mP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VHDL simulator maintains an *event queue*. This is the simulator's "To Do" list. The effect of executing any line of VHDL with a *signal assignment* is to modify the event queue. Usually, events are added to the event queue, but often events can also be removed. Events will be removed in order to model *inertial delays*; in VHDL delays are inertial by default.

> In order to model inertial delays, when an event is added to the event
>   queue, any event that is scheduled to occur at the same time or
>   earlier is removed, unless the effect of that event is the same as the
>   effect of the new event being added.

When your code is being executed, events are getting removed from the event queue by subsequent signal assignments. We need to analyse the event queue in detail.

So, at time 0 ns, the event queue is empty. This line gets executed at time 0

```
start <= '0', 
         '1' after  2*clk_period,
         '0' after  3*clk_period,
         '1' after  6*clk_period,
         '0' after  7*clk_period,
         '1' after 42*clk_period;
```

to put 6 events on to the event queue. The event queue now looks like this:

```
TIME      DELTA   SIGNAL    VALUE
   0 ns   1       start     '0'
 200 ns   0       start     '1'
 300 ns   0       start     '0'
 600 ns   0       start     '1'
 700 ns   0       start     '0'
4200 ns   0       start     '1'
```

At time 200 ns, `start` gets driven to `'1'` and so the following three lines get executed:

```
tsy <= '1' after 4*clk_period, '0' after 5*clk_period;
tsr <= '1' after 6*clk_period, '0' after 7*clk_period;
tlg <= '1' after 16*clk_period, '0' after 17*clk_period;
```

which put 6 more events on to the event queue. The event queue now looks like this:

```
TIME      DELTA   SIGNAL    VALUE
 300 ns   0       start     '0'
 600 ns   0       start     '1'
 600 ns   0       tsy       '1'
 700 ns   0       start     '0'
 700 ns   0       tsy       '0'
 800 ns   0       tsr       '1'
 900 ns   0       tsr       '0'
1800 ns   0       tlg       '1'
1900 ns   0       tlg       '0'
4200 ns   0       start     '1'
```

then at 300 ns `start` gets driven to `'0'` and so the event queue now looks like this:

```
TIME      DELTA   SIGNAL    VALUE
 600 ns   0       start     '1'
 600 ns   0       tsy       '1'
 700 ns   0       start     '0'
 700 ns   0       tsy       '0'
 800 ns   0       tsr       '1'
 900 ns   0       tsr       '0'
1800 ns   0       tlg       '1'
1900 ns   0       tlg       '0'
4200 ns   0       start     '1'
```

then at 600 ns `start` gets driven to `'1'` (and `tsy` gets driven to `'1'` too) and so the event queue now looks like this:

```
TIME      DELTA   SIGNAL    VALUE
 700 ns   0       start     '0'
 700 ns   0       tsy       '0'
 800 ns   0       tsr       '1'
 900 ns   0       tsr       '0'
1800 ns   0       tlg       '1'
1900 ns   0       tlg       '0'
4200 ns   0       start     '1'
```

and the following three lines get executed again:

```
tsy <= '1' after 4*clk_period, '0' after 5*clk_period;
tsr <= '1' after 6*clk_period, '0' after 7*clk_period;
tlg <= '1' after 16*clk_period, '0' after 17*clk_period;
```

which put 6 more events on to the event queue:

```
TIME      DELTA   SIGNAL    VALUE
1000 ns   0       tsy       '1'
1100 ns   0       tsy       '0'
1200 ns   0       tsr       '1'
1300 ns   0       tsr       '0'
2200 ns   0       tlg       '1'
2300 ns   0       tlg       '0'
```

If you follow the rule I gave above, you see the event queue looks like this:

```
TIME      DELTA   SIGNAL    VALUE
 700 ns   0       start     '0'
1000 ns   0       tsy       '1'
1100 ns   0       tsy       '0'
1200 ns   0       tsr       '1'
1300 ns   0       tsr       '0'
2200 ns   0       tlg       '1'
2300 ns   0       tlg       '0'
4200 ns   0       start     '1'
```

because these five events were deleted:

```
TIME      DELTA   SIGNAL    VALUE
 700 ns   0       tsy       '0'
 800 ns   0       tsr       '1'  
 900 ns   0       tsr       '0'
1800 ns   0       tlg       '1'
1900 ns   0       tlg       '0'
```

If you look at the trace, you see that these events are exactly what occur:

- the falling edge of `tsy` is deleted (hence the wide pulse);
- the first two events on `tsr` are deleted (hence only one pulse);
- the first two events on `tlg` are deleted (hence only one pulse).

Comment: Thank you for your time, that was a very informative answer.